# kubernetes: How can I see which pods are causing hostPort conflicts?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

Running into this problem when scheduling a pod.

```
1 node(s) didn't have free ports for the requested pod ports.
```

How can I see which pod on the node has a conflicting `hostPort` declaration?

EDIT: [I opened a PR against Kubernetes adding the port conflict into the error](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/112522). So if that gets merged, that'll be the answer I guess.

Comment: why are you using host ports for your pods in the first place?

Comment: DaemonSet ingress controller.

Comment: then there should be only one pod per node, so they should be no conflict between the pods. And you also know which pod has the conflicting configuration. Its the one from your deamon set.

Comment: I agree there should be no conflict. I don't believe anything else to be using these ports. And yet, there is. I don't know why. So I'm asking StackOverflow how I can check.

Comment: you can check the failing pod, when you do describe or get -o yaml you see what node it was supposed to be scheduled. You can go on that node and do a `netstat -ntulp` to see all used ports.

Comment: Hmm. Nothing obvious in there that seems to be listening on any of the hostPorts I'm requesting. Could it be in a different network namespace?

Comment: @ iameli Please check the cluster logs for each deployment you will be able to find out the ports and all ips. Please use this for checking the logs for each deployment:  kubectl logs deploy/my-deployment  & try to install the third party  monitoring tools to get the ip & port numbers EX:  NAGIOS.